# How jsAjaxForm from jQuery v2.1.3 changed in jQuery v3.2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am switching to higher version of jquery(3.2.1)
and facing difficulties with up-grade ajax file upload by jsAjaxForm in jQuery v2.1.3 functions.
Is there any function that does same role as jaAjaxForm in jQuery v3.2.1? or any suggestions?

I used to submit the form and jsAjaxForm will handle the rest of issue with uploading the file... and after applying jQuery v3.1.2 this function doesn't work anymore...

```
$("#frm").submit();

jsAjaxForm("POST", "/fcltsMange/fcltsInfoInsert", "frm", function(response, status){
        alert("!");
    if (response.result != null) {
        if (response.result == "success") {
            alert("success");
        }else{
            alert("fail");  
        }
    }
});
```

and this r.fn.load=function from jquery.min.js is where root-error happens...

```
r.fn.load=function(a,b,c){var d,e,f,g=this,.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the migrate plugin given below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.js"></script>
```

[Source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate)

Comment: you saved my friday night. love u :))